# How to setup SQLite with eclipse for the very first time?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to setup SQLite with eclipse using the documentation:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite

But when I am trying to add new "Generic JDBC" driver, the fields are disabled.

[image]

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Recent versions include SQLite in the **Vendor Filter** list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you are now, you need to select JAR List tab and import the sqlite.jar file which is inside the zip file downloaded in the earlier step. [Download from here.](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/javasqlite-20060714-win32.zip)

[image: Adding the SQLite jar file]

Once that is done, you can proceed as per the steps mentioned in the link. Hope it helps.